# Facebook Graph API - Events created by user

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the events created by a user using the Graph API. With FQL I can call the following:

```
SELECT name, location, description
FROM event WHERE creator = me()
AND start_time > now()
ORDER BY start_time';
```

But FQL has been deprecated as of v2.1.

There doesn't seem to be a documented way of doing this with the Graph API. Calling
`/{user-id}/events` gives a list of all the events a user is going to, but I can't find a way of filtering it to only events created by the user. Has anybody managed to do something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have also faced same problem today morning. 
While searching and doing lots of R&D i found some good and final solution to fetch events with graph-api.

Try using below url to find the events which are greater then your date.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/USERID/events?access_token=URACCESSTOKEN&fields=id,name,description,start_time,end_time,place&since=YOURSATRTDATE
```

**NOTE:**

1. The fields parameter is mandatory in v2.4.
2. since date should be in unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

With v2.5 I found out that you can use the "type" parameter in the following way to search for events created by a user:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/USERID/events?fields=id,name,description,start_time,end_time&type=created
```